# Run shell script or custom data on AKS node pool via terraform

Tags: azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I would like to run shell script or custom data on AKS node pool via terraform script. I ran shell script via custom data on VMSS (Virtual machine scale set) through terraform.Similarly I would like to run the same shell script via AKS node pool. I searched many link and ways but couldn't get any solution for this. Is there any way or recommended this? Appreciate your help.I have been trying for this solution since a month but couldn't get proper solution.

Comment: Any update please?

Comment: You can use locals to run script in your nodepool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got my solution via deamonset and configmap with nodeinstaller.
Below links really helped me but not through terraform as AKS won't support custom script to automate via terraform.([Hi can I have a custom script to be executed in AKS node group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65274149/hi-can-i-have-a-custom-script-to-be-executed-in-aks-node-group/65277140?noredirect=1#comment127673884_65277140))

Reference links: https://medium.com/@patnaikshekhar/initialize-your-aks-nodes-with-daemonsets-679fa81fd20e

https://github.com/patnaikshekhar/AKSNodeInstaller

**daemonset.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: node-installer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: installer
  namespace: node-installer
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      job: installer
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        job: installer
    spec:
      hostPID: true
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - image: patnaikshekhar/node-installer:1.3
        name: installer
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: install-script
          mountPath: /tmp
        - name: host-mount
          mountPath: /host
      volumes:
      - name: install-script
        configMap:
          name: sample-installer-config
      - name: host-mount
        hostPath:
          path: /tmp/install
```

**sampleconfigmap.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: sample-installer-config
  namespace: node-installer
data:
  install.sh: |
    #!/bin/bash

    # install newrelic-infra
    echo "license_key: #{NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY}#" | sudo tee -a /etc/newrelic-infra.yml
    echo "enabled: #{NEW_RELIC_INFRA_AGENT_ENABLED}#" | sudo tee -a /etc/newrelic-infra.yml

    curl -s https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/gpg/newrelic-infra.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
    printf "deb https://download.newrelic.com/infrastructure_agent/linux/apt bionic main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/newrelic-infra.list
    sudo apt-get update -y
    sudo apt-get install newrelic-infra -y
    sudo systemctl status newrelic-infra
    echo "Newrelic infra agent installation is done"

    # enable log forwarding
    echo "logs:" | sudo tee -a /etc/newrelic-infra/logging.d/logs.yml
    echo "  - name: log-files-in-folder" | sudo tee -a /etc/newrelic-infra/logging.d/logs.yml
    echo "    file: /var/log/onefc/*/*.newrelic.log" | sudo tee -a /etc/newrelic-infra/logging.d/logs.yml
    echo "    max_line_kb: 256" | sudo tee -a /etc/newrelic-infra/logging.d/logs.yml

    # trigger log forwarding
    sudo newrelic-infra-ctl
```